# How to get the index of an item at a specific offset from the top in Android ListView

Tags: android-widget, android-listview, android

Is there a simple way for getting the index of a list item which is in a specific offset from the top?
For example, get the index of an item which appears 150 pixels from the top.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could explain more about what you intend to do - this sounds like it may be an approach that wont work out well.

Comment: I want to know what's the index of the item which is located in the middle of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your goal is to find which list item is in the center of the screen, you could try something like the following:

(Make a custom class that extends ListView, such as MyListView.java)

```
public class MyListView extends ListView implements OnScrollListener {

public MyListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setOnScrollListener(this);
    }


@Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        // Center the child currently closest to the center of the ListView when
        // the ListView stops scrolling.
        if (scrollState == OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) { 

            int listViewCenterX = getWidth() / 2;
            int listViewCenterY = getHeight() / 2;

            Rect rect = new Rect();

            // Iterate the children and find which one is currently the most
            // centered.
            for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); ++i) {
                View child = getChildAt(i);
                child.getHitRect(rect);
                if (rect.contains(listViewCenterX, listViewCenterY)) {
                    // this listitem is in the "center" of the listview
                    // do what you want with it.
                    final int position = getPositionForView(child);
                    final int offset = listViewCenterY - (child.getHeight() / 2);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through children and check each ones hit rectangle against the point you have.